# How to convert Std class object data to array in php

Tags: php

```
 $postdata= "stdClass Object
    (
    [created] => 1326853478
    [livemode] => 
    [id] => evt_00000000000000
    [type] => invoice.payment_succeeded    
...........................
        ))";

$event = json_decode($postdata);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($event);
```

Can't `std class object` to `array` in php?I am using `json_decode` but its not working just get empty array.I am giving my result data std class object assign in variable its anything wrong that's why its showing not working?

Comment: That can't be that actual data you're trying to JSON decode, right?

Comment: As a side note, with json_decode, setting the second arg to true will return you an array (though currently it looks like you're trying to decode the output of a `var_dump` O_o

Comment: assign that std class object is wrong?$event = json_decode($postdata,true);
                
                var_dump($event);
                exit; Get null value

Comment: `$postdata` is not an object in this case, it is a string. This string is also not valid JSON. If it was an object you could simply do `$event = (array) $postData`. Is there a reason you have it this way?

Comment: Everyone is confused. Is that your actual code or is the `stdClass` output from a `print_r()` or something

Comment: i want to check my output with manual thats why i am copy my output value to assign variable.

Answer (score 2):

you can use :

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to cast it:

```
$array = (array) $stdClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$event = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($event);
```